# Prove that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Knowing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, I must prove that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Teacher's proof:

For each $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, let $A_a = \{(a,q) : q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ so that $A_a \sim \mathbb{Q}$. So each $A_a$ is countable, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is known to be countable already. Since $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} = \bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{Q}} A_a$, and knowing that the union of countable sets is countable, we deduce that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable. (End of proof.)

How do I show exactly, based on the definition of $A_a$, that $A_a \sim \mathbb{Q}$? I thought about showing that $A_a$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ have the same cardinality. Is it possible to show that? Intuitively, if $\mathbb{Q}$ has a certain countable number of elements, and $(a,q)$ is based on fixed $a$ and variable $q$, so $A_a$ has that same number of elements as $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function $\phi_a:\mathbb Q\to A_a$ as follows: $$\phi_a(q)\equiv(a,q)\quad\forall q\in\mathbb Q.$$ Show that $\phi_a$ is injective [that is, $\phi_a(q_1)=\phi_a(q_2)$ implies $q_1=q_2$ for any $q_1,q_2,\in\mathbb Q$] and that it is also surjective [that is, each element of $A_a$ is the image of some $q\in \mathbb Q$ under $\phi_a$]. By the [Cantor–Bernstein–Schröder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem), this shows that $\mathbb Q$ has the same cardinality as $A_a$.

EDIT: As user84413 pointed out in a comment below, the Cantor–Bernstein–Schröder theorem is an overkill here. It is sufficient to observe that $\phi_a$ is a bijection.

Comment: (I don't think you need the CSB theorem for this, since you have actually given a bijection between the 2 sets.)

Comment: @user84413 Thank you, duly noted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $A_a$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{Q}$ through, for instance,
$$f:A_a\to \mathbb{Q}$$
$$(a,q)\mapsto q$$.

They have the same cardinality since they are in bijection.