# Prove that $\mathbb{|Q|} = \mathbb{|Q \times Q|} $

Tags: equivalence-relations

This question exists, but **both cases have a specific answer for the OP's situation**. I do not know how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Questions I am referring to:
[Prove that $\mathbb{|Q| = |Q\times Q|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503704/prove-q-qq) and
[Prove that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939582/prove-that-mathbbq-times-mathbbq-is-countable?rq=1)

Comment: Does $\ast$ stands for Cartesian product?

Comment: Yes but I do not know how to write the conventional symbol, unless I simply use x?

Comment: You can just use \times: $\times$

Comment: `\times` will produce the correct symbol.

Comment: Also, " I am in no such situation where I know $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. " is a strange sentence... Do you mean that you don't know how to prove it and then cannot use it in your proof?

Comment: Yes thank you Shan'do Taladris. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You can check that

$$\varphi(\frac{p}{q},\frac{r}{s})=\frac{2^p3^q}{5^r7^s}$$

where $p$ and $q$ are integers with no common factor and $q$ is positive, and similarly for $r$ and $s$, is an injection of ${\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}$ into ${\mathbb Q}$.

On a side note, if you study about cardinals of sets, it is a good idea to prove that ${\mathbb Q}$ is countable, sooner or later.